# Help with writing proofs

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

1. Prove that for any sets A, B and C if A  is a subset of B, then  A – C  is a subset of  B – C.

Answer (score 5):

take any $x\in A-C$. You have $x\in A$ but $x\notin C$. Since $A$ is a subset of $B$ it follows that $x\in A$ implies $x\in B$. This means $x\in B$ but $x\notin C$. You write this as $x\in  B-C$. Since $x$ was taken arbitrarily you have that for all $x\in A-C$ it follows $x\in B-C$. Therefore $A-C\subset B-C$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof of roughly the same length, but in a different (calculational) format:
$$
\begin{align}
& A - C \subset B - C \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\subset$; definition of $-$, twice"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A \land x \not\in C \Rightarrow x \in B \land x \not\in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: simplify: assume part of antecedent of $\Rightarrow$ in consequent"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A \land x \not\in C \Rightarrow x \in B \rangle \\
(*) \Leftarrow & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: weaken by strengthening antecedent of $\Rightarrow$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\subset$"} \\
& A \subset B \\
\end{align}
$$
All steps are really uncreative, except for the key step $(*)$, which is strongly suggested by the shape of the formulae.